# Call to undefined function updateTable()

Tags: php

I'm new to programming and I start working alone. I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function updateTable() in D:\xampp\htdocs\demo\mysql\login_update.php on line 6

If I paste the function `updateTable()` in other file and then call it, the error disappears, but if I let the function in `functions.php`, the error persists. Does somebody know why this happen? Thank you!

This is `db.php`:

```
<?php
    $connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '', 'loginapp');
    if(!$connection){
        echo 'Nu suntem conectati la baza de date!'; 
    }
?>
```

This is `functions.php`:

```
<?php include "db.php";?>

<?php
function showAlldata() {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM  login";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if(!$result) {
        die("Eroare" . mysqli_error());
    }

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $id=$row['id'];  
    echo "<option value='$id'>$id</option>";
    }
}

function updateTable() {
    global $connection;
    $username=$_POST['username']; 
    $password=$_POST['password']; 
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $query="UPDATE login SET ";
    $query.="username='$username', ";
    $query.="password='$password' ";
    $query.="WHERE id=$id";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection, $query); 

    if(!$result) {
        die("Eroare Query" . mysqli_error($connection));
     } 
}
?>
```

And this is my `login_update` file:

```
<?php include "db.php"; ?> 
<?php include "functions.php"; ?>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  updateTable();     
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Update</title>
</head>
<body>

   <form action="login_update.php" method="post">    
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Insert username"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Insert password"><br>
        <select name="id" id="">
            <?php showAllData();  ?>         
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Enable error-reporting. Is the file successfully included?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: better use 'require_once' than include. Then you'll get an error if the file isn't found/included.

Comment: also right now you're including db.php _twice_.

Comment: in login_update file do this after the include lines `var_dump(get_included_files());`. What is the result

Comment: I solved the problem. I just copy al functions in new file "functii.php". Thank you !